# How do I get Sphinx code blocks working as tabs?

Tags: python-sphinx

I have tried the extension sphinx-tabs. I use Python 3.8 and the latest Sphinx ver.

I install with pip and add to conf.py but my code is never displayed properly.

In conf.py I have this:
extensions = ['sphinx_tabs.tabs']

My code is simple:

```
.. tabs::
    .. tab:: tab1
        Content for tab one

    .. tab:: tab2
        Content for tab two
```

This just produces the text:

tab1

tab2

Both appear to be hyperlinks but do not actually link anywhere.

Comment: conf.py has:
extensions = ['sphinx_tabs.tabs']

Comment: The code is simply:

.. tabs::
  .. tab:: tab1  
     Content for tab one
    
  .. tab:: tab2  
     Content for tab two

Comment: OK, my above 2 comments both relate to the sphinx_tabs extension. But I included all 3 as I suspect that the same problem in my setup is causing all of them to fail.

Comment: sphinx-tabs (https://github.com/djungelorm/sphinx-tabs#installation) works for me. Without more details, I don't know how to diagnose your problem.

Comment: This is the html produced, if that helps (in 2 comments to fit it in):
<div class="sphinx-tabs docutils container">
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu sphinx-menu docutils container">
<div class="active item sphinx-data-tab-0-0 docutils container">
<div class="docutils container">
<p>tab1</p>
</div>
</div>

Comment: <div class="item sphinx-data-tab-0-1 docutils container">
<div class="docutils container">
<p>tab2</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached sphinx-tab tab segment sphinx-data-tab-0-0 active docutils container">
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached sphinx-tab tab segment sphinx-data-tab-0-1 docutils container">
</div>
</div>

Comment: It just produces two apparent hyperlinks named tab1 and tab2, one above the other. The text is blue and the cursor changes to a hand when I move over one but neither actually links to anywhere,

Comment: Please avoid piling on more comments. Instead, **edit the question**. Include a screen shot. Explain how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Whitespace is sometimes crucial. Add a blank line immediately before "Content for tab one" and "Content for tab two". Does that help? Notice the blank lines in this example: https://github.com/djungelorm/sphinx-tabs#basic-tabs

Comment: Thanks. I inserted blanks as suggested (and after the first ..tabs:: line). This outputs the two "Content for" lines but only after both of the tab statements, which are still not acting as tabs.

Comment: The problem is that I am not getting tabs side by side that show the content alternately as I click on each tab. The idea is that once I get them working, I will show code in 2 languages on the 2 tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that are different between your code and mine:

- I found I needed extra lines everywhere, and
- for code especially, the `code-block` tag is great! (otherwise just go with `tab`).

```
.. tabs::

    .. code-tab:: cpp

        auto hello = someCPlusPlusFunction();

    .. code-tab:: python

        howdy = some_python_function()
```